# Select info from joined recordset where row has Max Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two related tables that form an order system. The first table shows general order info (including the order date), and the second table breaks down each order by the materials ordered.

I'm trying to get the most recent order info for each material we have in our system. So, for material 10A, I would need to get the information for order 2.

| Order | Order Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-01-01 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 |
| 3 | 2018-01-01 |

| Order | Material |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10A |
| 1 | 20B |
| 2 | 10A |
| 3 | 10A |
| 3 | 30C |

I've inner joined the two tables to get this so far, but I can't figure out how to filter out orders 1 and 3 for material 10A. I tried using MAX() on the Order Date, but it doesn't work as I have to group by the rest of the columns. I can't use a MAX() on Order since dates do not always increase with the order #. Here's what I've tried:

```
SELECT POIT.Material, POHD.Order, MAX(POHD.OrderDate) 
FROM POIT
    INNER JOIN POHD ON POHD.Order = POIT.Order
GROUP BY POIT.Material, POHD.Order
ORDER BY POIT.Material
```

Results:

| Material | Order | Order Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10A | 1 | 2019-01-01 |
| 10A | 2 | 2020-01-01 |
| 10A | 3 | 2018-01-01 |
| 20B | 1 | 2019-01-01 |
| 30C | 3 | 2018-01-01 |

This is what I expect:

| Material | Order | Order Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10A | 2 | 2020-01-01 |
| 20B | 1 | 2019-01-01 |
| 30C | 3 | 2018-01-01 |

Using MS SQL Server 2019

Comment: Show us what you have done so far.

Comment: And the result you expect as a table.

Comment: @DaleK Updated the post with work and expected/actual

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A row-numbering solution should work.**

This avoids the need to self-join:

```sql
SELECT Material, [Order], OrderDate
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER
           (PARTITION BY POHD.Order ORDER BY POHD.OrderDate DESC) rn
    FROM POIT
    INNER JOIN POHD ON POHD.Order = POIT.Order
) p
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY POIT.Material
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the join you had but without the group by and add a subquery on the join to match on the max date and value.

```
SELECT POIT.[Material]
        , POHD.[Order]
        , POHD.[OrderDate]
FROM POIT 
INNER JOIN POHD
    ON POHD.[Order] = POIT.[Order]
    AND POHD.[OrderDate] = (SELECT MAX(POHD2.OrderDate) 
                          FROM POHD AS POHD2
                          WHERE POHD.[Order] = POHD2.[Order])
    AND POIT.[Material] =  (SELECT MAX(POIT2.[Material]) 
                          FROM POIT AS POIT2
                          WHERE POIT2.[Order] = POIT.[Order])
ORDER BY POIT.Material
```

**RESULTS**

| Material | Order | OrderDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10A | 2 | 2020-01-01 |
| 20B | 1 | 2019-01-01 |
| 30C | 3 | 2018-01-01 |